# dynamic ImageIcon reduction for setFrameIcon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jinternalframe, imageicon

I have an ImageIcon that I used for a button to open this skillsFrame.  This size of the image is 100x100px.  As you can see in the screenshot if I just put the image it is too large(which is expected).

My question is about how to scale the image to 16x16(or whatever the default size is) so that I don't need to manually create a smaller sized version(for multiple reasons).

1. In case they make windows bigger in the future
2. Multiple operating system support
3. I'm sure I don't need to go on naming more...

   skillsFrame = new JInternalFrame("Skills", true, true, false, false);

   skillsFrame.setFrameIcon(new ImageIcon("images/gui/button_skills.png"));

And now for the image... the bar at the tops is the buttons to click to open the various JInternalFrames.

[image: [IMG]http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4310/67719353.png[/IMG]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to scale the image to 16x16(or whatever the default size is)

you have look at [Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: @trashgod event I never had any issue with that, thank you excelent catch

Comment: @mKorbel: Nor have I, but I keep the link handy. :-)